# Transition matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the following dataframe:

```
 df = data.frame(cusip = paste("A", 1:10, sep = ""), xt = c(1,2,3,2,3,5,2,4,5,1), xt1 = c(1,4,2,1,1,4,2,2,2,5))
```

The data is divided in **five states**, which are **quantiles** in reality: *1,2,3,4,5*.
The first column of the dataframe represents the state at time *t*, and the second column is the state at time *t+1*.

I would like to compute a sort of a transition matrix for the five states. The meaning of the matrix would be as follows:

- (Row, Col) = (1,1) : % of cusips that were in quantile 1 at time *t*,
  and stayed at 1 in time *t+1*
- (Row, Col) = (1,2) : % of cusips that were in quantile 1 at *t*, and
  became quantile 2 at *t+1*
- etc...

I am really not sure how to do this in an efficient way. I have the feeling the answer is trivial, but I just can't get my head around it.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res <- with(df, table(xt, xt1)) ## table() to form transition matrix
res/rowSums(res)                ## /rowSums() to normalize by row
#    xt1
# xt          1         2         4         5
#   1 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
#   2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
#   3 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#   4 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#   5 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000

## As an alternative to  2nd line above, use sweep(), which won't rely on 
## implicit recycling of vector returned by rowSums(res)
sweep(res, MARGIN = 1, STATS = rowSums(res), FUN = `/`)
```

Comment: Perfect!! Could you please elaborate as to what the first line does?

Comment: Given n arguments, `table()` forms a n-dimensional array whose elements contain the numbers of times each particular combination of `xt` and `xt1` appear in your data. `with(df, ...)` just forms a local evaluation environment within which `xt` and `xt1` (and any other named columns in `df`) will be directly visible: that statement is essentially shorthand for `table(df$xt, df$xt1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer! Very helpful!

Comment: Also `prop.table(res,1)`. I don't think that wheel needs reinventing, eh?

Comment: @Frank Sure, though I typically prefer knowing about the more general function (here `sweep()`) and how it works, so that I can quickly apply it in a broad range of circumstances. It's probably for similar reasons that `?prop.table` describes the function by stating, "This is really ‘sweep(x, margin, margin.table(x, margin), "/")’ for newbies [...]"!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the states (1..5) in the column of the transition matrix, you can try this:

```
levs <- sort(union(df$xt, df$xt1)) 
tbl <- table(factor(df$xt, levs), factor(df$xt1, levs))
tbl / rowSums(tbl)  

         1         2         3         4         5
  1 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
  2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000
  3 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  4 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
  5 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
```