# compute weighted transition matrix in r

Tags: r

I found this question interesting:
[Transition matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391984/transition-matrix-in-r)

So following his setup, suppose I add a weight (xt2) to each row:

```
 >df = data.frame(cusip = paste("A", 1:10, sep = ""), xt = c(1,2,3,2,3,5,2,4,5,5), xt1 = c(1,4,2,1,1,4,2,2,2,2),xt2=c(1:10));df
   cusip xt xt1 xt2
1     A1  1   1   1
2     A2  2   4   2
3     A3  3   2   3
4     A4  2   1   4
5     A5  3   1   5
6     A6  5   4   6
7     A7  2   2   7
8     A8  4   2   8
9     A9  5   2   9
10   A10  5   2  10
```

Using the answer in that post, we get the transition matrix:

```
res <- with(df, table(xt, xt1))
    xt1
 xt  1 2 4
   1 1 0 0
   2 1 1 1
   3 1 1 0
   4 0 1 0
   5 0 2 1
result <- res/rowSums(res) ;a
        xt1
 xt          1         2         4
   1 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
   2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
   3 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
   4 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
   5 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

But what if I want to compute the transition matrix weighted by the `xt2` column? That is to say, when we generate `res`, we do not just count the frequency of change of state, we use actual numbers (the weight). For example, `res[2,1]` should be 4, and `res[5,2]` should be 9+10=19.
Therefore, the new `res` wanted should be like the following:

```
    xt1
 xt  1 2 4
   1 1 0 0
   2 4 7 2
   3 5 3 0
   4 0 8 0
   5 0 19 6
```

And then, we can just calculate `result` using the same code above. 
How can I achieve that `res`? Thank you.

P.S., Or is there any other way to "weight" the transition matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `xtabs`.  Using the formula method, we specify the cross-classifying variables on the rhs of `~` and the vector of counts on the lhs.  By default, it will do the `sum`

```
xtabs(xt2~xt+xt1, df)
#    xt1
#xt   1  2  4
#  1  1  0  0
#  2  4  7  2
#  3  5  3  0
#  4  0  8  0
#  5  0 19  6
```

Or with `tapply`, we group by 'xt', 'xt1' and specify the `FUN` as `sum`.  For those elements that don't have a combination, it will give `NA`, which can be replaced to 0 if necessary.

```
with(df, tapply(xt2, list(xt, xt1), FUN=sum))
```

---

Or we can use `acast` from `reshape2`.  We reshape from 'long' to 'wide' by specifying the formula and the `value.var` column.

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, xt~xt1, value.var='xt2', sum)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate `xt2~xt+xt1` a little?

Comment: @Natalia Added some description.  Hope it helps.  For more info, you can check `?xtabs`